# ASP.NET MVC: Mobile Layout being used with non-mobile view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

I have been working on a mobile version of my site's main page using this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx as guide.

I have two controllers: HomeController and EventController

HomeController has a Index view and EventController has a Detail view

I managed to create a Index.mobile.cshtml view that uses _Layout.mobile.cshtml correctly. Now when a user visits mysite.com/Home/Index on her phone it shows the mobile version correctly.

Now, I would have expected that if the same user visits mysite.com/Event/Detail/123, the default "Desktop" view would show (I **DO NOT** have a Detail.mobile.cshtml view).

The problem is that the Detail.cshtml view is indeed invoked, but it tries to use the _Layout.mobile.cshtml layout, making the page look awful.

Is there a way to achieve this (just rendering the desktop view **with the desktop layout** for the ones that I haven't implemented on mobile)?

Thanks!

Comment: The Stack Exchange developers wrote a great article on implementing mobile views in ASP .NET MVC here http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/17/mobile-views-in-asp-net-mvc3/

Comment: Are you using MVC4 or MVC5?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to the end of your _ViewStart.cshtml file:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.RequireConsistentDisplayMode = true;
```

This will stop the application from showing non-mobile views within your mobile layout and vice-versa.

Comment: Good ! There are a small mistake, the property's name is RequireConsistentDisplayMode not RequiresConsistentDisplayMode

Comment: @jbbi okay thanks, I'll take your word for it ;-) updated as indicated

Answer (score 1):

Note it appears that you can solve this problem on a per view basis by placing this line of code in the Controller Action.

`HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Desktop);`

However, what I'd really like is a solution that basically says if the current view doesn't have the .Mobile in the name/path, don't switch the Layout to a .Mobile version

Answer (score 1):

I didn't used this [NUGET Pakage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MobileViewEngines) before, but **Note that it mentioned :**

> By default it will let you switch back and forth between Desktop and
>   Mobile but only on mobile devices. Why? Check out the first line of
>   code:
>   And code checks the Mobile Device first as follow:

```
@if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
{
    <div class="view-switcher ui-bar-a">
        @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice)
        {
            @: Displaying mobile view
            @Html.ActionLink("Desktop view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = false, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
        } 
        else 
        {
            @: Displaying desktop view
            @Html.ActionLink("Mobile view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = true, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
        }
    </div>
}
```

**According to MSDN :**

> In general, we recommend that you avoid having logic in your views. It
>   can be difficult to discover and even more difficult to test. Instead,
>   logic in views should be moved into view models or controller actions.

*Problem Solving:* Change default logic based on your need, Perhaps by Tracing Views (Break Points work on Views too) to meet your purpose.

You need to see [This MSDN Topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149688.aspx) to be aware in conjunction of MVC and named Package too. Understanding what happens in Action can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The esiest solution would be to override Layout on Detail.cshtml explicitly using _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If you want more generic solution, you may try the following:

Create custom DisplayMode:

```
public class MobileDisplayMode : IDisplayMode
{
    private bool _mobileViewWasUsed = false;

    public override DisplayInfo GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, string virtualPath, Func<string, bool> virtualPathExists)
    {
        string filePath = this.TransformPath(virtualPath, this._suffix);
        if (filePath != null && virtualPathExists(filePath))
        {
            if (!_mobileViewWasUsed)
            {
                if (virtualPath.IndexOf("layout", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                    return (DisplayInfo) null;

                _mobileViewWasUsed = true;
            }
            return new DisplayInfo(filePath, (IDisplayMode) this);
        }
        else
            return (DisplayInfo) null;
    }
}
```

Add it in global.asax:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new MobileDisplayMode("mobile"));
```

Unfortunately, have no chance to test it while it's based on some unapproved assumptions (like creation of DisplayMode per request and others). Anyways, if you are interested and have a chance to test it, it would be wonderful.